# Export data from Power Bi and create xlsx file at SharePoint

Tags: automation, powerbi, power-automate

Can you export data from Power Bi and create xlsx file without need of prepared xlsx template at SharePoint?

If no I am trying the following flow:

[image]

which is not working in the step compose where no data "drops" to input. Even when I have seen many videos combining run a query against a dataset followed by compose action with reference to first table rows from the run a query against a dataset step. Any suggestion please?

Adding create a table as csv between those steps fetch the needed data but data type becomes string instead of needed array for the last step as adding rows to the table.